# Data Structure to filter all pairwise-greater points?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

What is a good implementation of the following?

The data structure in question must not contain any point that is pairwise-greater-than another.  e.g. (2,11) > (1,10), (5, 5) not-gt (1,5).  And inputs occur online, so they cannot be pre-ordered/prepared.

[image: Example input]

Alright, this can be shown with the image above.  So, each point is inserted in the order indicated, as follows:

1. (2,2) inserted
2. (2,4) inserted, not > (2,2) and vice versa so both remain
3. (3,3) > (2,2) and so is not inserted
4. (1,1); all others > so (1,1) inserted while all others removed

Ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't be enough to keep a BST sorted by min(x, y) and when inserting a pair (x', y') remove any pairs with min(x, y) > max(x', y')?

Answer (score 1):

Start with the array of points (-Inf, Inf) and (Inf, -Inf)

Order the elements in array with respect to below rule

```
for (x,y) and (t,z)
if x<t (x,t) is before (t,z)
if x=t and y>z then (x,t) is before (t,z)
```

When you want to insert an element, find the element with highest order that is before the inserted element and call it EBefore. Also find the element with lowest order which is after the inserted element and call it EAfter. You may use binary search while finding these two elements.

If vectoral product of

```
EInserted x (EAfter - EBefore) > 0
```

remove the all the elemets between EBefore and EAfter and insert EInserted between them. If the product is negative then do not add the element.

Answer (score 0):

Singly linked list with points that is pairwise-less-than another.

Consider the situation of comparisons a new point for each point in list at current step.
Сheck: our point less than a checking point in list?

If so, remove from list checking point.

Otherwise, simply add a new point to the list.

At the end, list have such points.